# Finding maximum value of a short int variable in C

Tags: c, size, short, typecase

I was working on Exercise 2-1 of K&R, the goal is to calculate the range of different variable types, bellow is my function to calculate the maximum value a `short int` can contain:

```
short int max_short(void) {
    short int i = 1, j = 0, k = 0;
    while (i > k) {
        k = i;
        if (((short int)2 * i) > (short int)0)
            i *= 2;
        else {
            j = i;
            while (i + j <= (short int)0)
                j /= 2;
            i += j;
        }
    }
    return i;
}
```

My problem is that the returned value by this function is: `-32768` which is obviously wrong since I'm expecting a positive value. I can't figure out where the problem is, I used the same function (with changes in the variables types) to calculate the maximum value an int can contain and it worked...

I though the problem could be caused by comparison inside the `if` and `while` statements, hence the typecasting but that didn't help...

Any ideas what is causing this ? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** Thanks to Antti Haapala for his explanations, the overflow to the sign bit results in undefined behavior NOT in negative values.

Comment: Short int is a signed type and it overflows to negative range if value exceeds its positive capacity. Your best bet is to see 'limits.h'

Comment: @Saleem the statement "overflows to negative range if value exceeds" is unfortunately incorrect. The correct statement is "behaviour is undefined".

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, my apologies. You are correct!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use calculations like this to deduce the range of *signed integers*, because signed integer overflow has *undefined behaviour*, and narrowing conversion at best results in an implementation-defined value, or a signal being raised. The proper solution is to  just use `SHRT_MAX`, `INT_MAX` ... of `<limits.h>`. Deducing the maximum value of *signed integers* via arithmetic is a trick question in standardized C language, and has been so ever since the first standard was published in 1989.

Note that the original edition of K&R predates the standardization of C by **11** years, and even the **2nd** one - the "ANSI-C" version *predates* the finalized standard and differs from it somewhat - they were written for a language that wasn't almost, but not quite, entirely unlike the C language of this day.

You can do it easily for unsigned integers though:

```
unsigned int i = -1;
// i now holds the maximum value of `unsigned int`.
```

Comment: Oh, my understanding was if you keep multiplying a '1' by two, the '1' would end up being shifted all the way to the sign-bit position, making the whole variable negative...
So there is no way to compute the maximum value? I think the point of the exercise is to find a calculation to do so

Comment: @Ryuuzaki_kun no, shifting 1 to the sign-bit position has undefined behaviour, whether by `<<`, `+`, or `*`...

Comment: @Ryuuzaki_kun this undefined behaviour allows many optimizations, such as https://kristerw.blogspot.fi/2016/02/how-undefined-signed-overflow-enables.html - and it is one of the biggest caveats in the C programming language.

Comment: I'm not so sure it is a trick question. Check my answer for one method. I can't think of a scenario where it will fail - it should cover obscure one's complement and sign & magnitude systems too.

Comment: You might want to add that this method is obsolete because non portable and the C Standard specifies arithmetic overflow as undefined behavior since 1990. K&R predates that by more than 15 years and it used to be an *accepted* approach to test the wrap around.

Answer (score 0):

Per definition, you cannot calculate the maximum value of a type in C, by using variables of that very same type. It simply doesn't make any sense. The type will overflow when it goes "over the top". In case of signed integer overflow, the behavior is undefined, meaning you will get a major bug if you attempt it.

The correct way to do this is to simply check `SHRT_MAX` from limits.h.

An alternative, somewhat more questionable way would be to create the maximum of an `unsigned short` and then divide that by 2. We can create the maximum by taking the bitwise inversion of the value 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main()
{ 
  printf("%hd\n", SHRT_MAX); // best way

  unsigned short ushort_max = ~0u;
  short short_max = ushort_max / 2;
  printf("%hd\n", short_max);

  return 0;
}
```

---

One note about your code:

Casts such as `((short int)2*i)>(short int)0` are completely superfluous. Most binary operators in C such as `*` and `>` implement something called "the usual arithmetic conversions", which is a way to implicitly convert and balance types of an expression. These implicit conversion rules will silently make both of the operands type `int` despite your casts.

Comment: Corner case that  fails with this approach: The max value of a signed integer may equal the max value of the corresponding unsigned integer.  Such implementations are exceedingly rare, yet allowed by C.  I have only encounter such with the widest unsigned type and not `short`.

Comment: Minor: `unsigned short ushort_max = ~0u;` is OK with `unsigned short`, yet not good when the destination type is wider that `unsigned`.  `some_unsigned_type u_max = -1;` is better.

Comment: @chux As far as I know, the C language only allows three forms of signedness, those listed in 6.2.6.2/2: one's complement, two's complement and sign & magnitude. Everything else is non-compliant.

Comment: As for the second comment, this answer is explicitly about `signed short`.

Comment: Consider a 36-bit two's complement - no padding and a 35-bit unsigned with 1 padding.  The max is the same for both.

Comment: @Lundin chux' is reading the standard same way as me. The positive range of the signed type must be a subrange of that of unsigned type, but having the same range would be acceptable.

Answer (score -2):

You forgot to cast to short int during comparison

OK, here I assume that the computer would handle integer overflow behavior by changing into negative integers, as I believe that you have assumed in writing this program.

code that outputs 32767:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
short int max_short(void)
{
    short int i = 1, j = 0, k = 0;
    while (i>k)
    {
        k = i;
        if (((short int)(2 * i))>(short int)0)
            i *= 2;
        else
        {
            j = i;
            while ((short int)(i + j) <= (short int)0)
                j /= 2;
            i += j;
        }
    }

    return i;
}

int main() {
    printf("%d", max_short());
    while (1);
}
```

added 2 casts

Comment: Also, the casts are pure nonsense. After the cast, the usual arithmetic conversions are still performed on both operands of a relational operator. Meaning that it ends up as `int` anyway. Also, this isn't tagged C++.

Comment: I know, but this is what the poster is trying to do and it actually can output the correct value though its not actually valid

Comment: "3 Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised."

Comment: The cast in `(short int)(2 * i)` makes some sense in that the `int` product `2*i`, if it does not overflow,  is converted to an `short` in an "implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.".  True that the result is then promoted to an `int`, but the narrowing of the product means that `((short int)(2 * i))>(short int)0)` is not necessarily functionally the same as `(2 * i>0)`