# Why does my program repeat forever instead of giving the maximum integer value?

Tags: c, integer, unsigned, signed

I am currently learning C, and I made a program that I thought would give me the maximum integer value, but it just loops forever. I can't find an answer as to why it won't end.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned int i = 0;
    signed int j = i;
    for(; i+1 == ++j; i++);
    printf(i);
    return 0;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: This code doesn't compile, the printf is incorrect. Do you have warnings turned on in your compiler?  This isn't an exact duplicate, but it should help you understand what is happening. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17293749/sizeof-operator-in-if-statement

Comment: You're experiencing unsigned integer overflow. The output should hint that something's up when i starts back at zero again.

Comment: What will terminate a loop that uses `i = 1, j = 0` and tests `i == ++j` then increments `i` and does the same test again?? (e.g. `1 == 1`, `2 == 2`, etc..)

Comment: You're also experiencing *signed integer overflow*, `runtime error: signed integer overflow: 2147483647 + 1 cannot be represented in type 'int'`, which makes the behaviour of your program as a whole, undefined. How do you think you could deduce the maximum integer value like this *at all*?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45882317/finding-maximum-value-of-a-short-int-variable-in-c

Comment: Maybe it is trying to tell you that there's no such thing as maximum integer value?

Comment: Copy/paste code that you have tested.  Don't just transcribe from printed text and post - you will make typos and waste everyone's time:(

Answer (score 4):

Your code has undefined behavior. And that's not because of `unsigned` integer overflow (it wraps when the value is too big). It is the `signed` integer overflow that is undefined behavior.

Also note that if your intention is to know the maximum value that an `int` can hold use the macro `INT_MAX`.

```
 maximum value for an object of type int
 INT_MAX                                +32767 // 215 - 1
```

Your should write the `printf` properly. (Pass the format specifier then the other arguments as specified by format specifier).

Comment: Isn't signed to unsigned conversion well defined? The signed value is converted to unsigned for the comparison, but is it for the preincrement as well?

Comment: @RetiredNinja.: In comparison yes - in pre-increment no.

Answer (score 3):

> I thought would give me the maximum integer value

The maximum `signed int` value cannot be portably found experimentally with out risking *undefined behavior* (UB).  In OP's code, eventually `++j` overflows (UB).  UB includes *loops forever*.

As [@coderredoc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48313463/2410359) well answered, instead use `printf("%d\n", INT_MAX);`

---

To find the maximum `unsigned value`:

```
printf("%u\n", UINT_MAX);
// or 
unsigned maxu = -1u;
printf("%u\n", maxu);
```